# Symfony: clone object with Datetime field and add days to cloned object dates

Tags: symfony, datetime, clone

I have an apparently simple problem but after several hours of try-and-error I only get wrong results.

The goal is to duplicate an object `Convention` with a OneToMany relation to `HallReservation` and add some days to this reservations. The result I get is, the days are added in the cloned objects and in the original objects, I want the original objects to remain unaltered.

This is the significant code:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Convention
{
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="HallReservation", mappedBy="convention", cascade={"all"})
 */
private $hallReservation;

/**
 * Clone object
 *
 */
public function __clone()
{
    if ($this->id)
    {
        $this->id=null;
        $this->reference = null;
        $this->registrationDate = new \Datetime('now');

        foreach ($this->hallReservation as $hallR)
        {
            $clonedR = clone $hallR;
            $clonedR->setConvention($this);
            $newRDate = clone $hallR->getDate();
            $clonedR->setDate($newRDate);
            $this->hallReservation->add($clonedR);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class HallReservation
{
/**
 * @var \Date
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="date")
 */
private $date;

/**
 * Clone object
 *
 */
public function __clone()
{
    if ($this->id)
    {
        $this->id=null;
        $clonedDate = clone $this->date;
        $this->date = $clonedDate;

}
```

**Controller code:**

```
        $jumpInterval = $originalConventionBeginDate->diff($newDate);
        foreach ($newConvention->getHallReservation() as $newHallR)
        {
            $prevDate = clone $newHallR->getDate();
            $prevDate->add($jumpInterval);

            $newHallR->setDate($prevDate);
        }
        $em->persist($newConvention);
        $em->flush();
```

As you see I clone datetime object **everywhere** but still the original convention hall reservations dates are also being added.

Comment: Did you try to log in the `if ($this->id)` blocks ? You could consider to create your new entites manually in a service without `__clone` method :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you clone the `Convention` object you do not set the `hallReservation` property to a new `Collection`. A `OneToMany` relation in Doctrine is mapped to a `Collection` object, so when you clone the `Convention` object, you get a reference to the original `hallReservation` collection in the cloned object.

You could try something like this:

```
<?php

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Convention
{
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="HallReservation", mappedBy="convention", cascade={"all"})
 */
private $hallReservation;

/**
 * Clone object
 *
 */
public function __clone()
{
    if ($this->id)
    {
        $this->id=null;
        $this->reference = null;
        $this->registrationDate = new \Datetime('now');
        $reservations = new ArrayCollection();

        foreach ($this->hallReservation as $hallR)
        {
            $clonedR = clone $hallR;
            $clonedR->setConvention($this);
            $newRDate = clone $hallR->getDate();
            $clonedR->setDate($newRDate);
            $reservations->add($clonedR);
        }

        $this->hallReservation = $reservations;
    }
}
```